# Subtract the index of one dataframe from a list with another data frame of a different list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, indexing

I have two lists of data frame, with binary values in them.

As an example : The first list is `lst1` and it contains the following values

```
$`4`
 [1] "N" "N" "N" "A" "A" "A" "A" "N" 

$`7`
 [1] "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N"
```

The second list is `lst2` and it contains the following values

```
$`4`
 [1] "N" "N" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "N" "N" "N" 
$`7`
 [1] "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N"
```

I want to subtract the index of `lst2` from `lst1` at the first instance of `"A"`.

So in `lst1`, at dataframe `` $`4` `` , the index value of `"A"` is **4**. similarly in `lst2` at `` $`4` `` , the index value of `"A"` is **3** . The difference between them would be **4-3 = 1**. And so on for other data frames in the list.

I have tried looking for a couple of solutions, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function to calculate the expected difference. It returns a list with the same names as the argument lists, with the calculated difference.

Keep in mind two important things:

- The difference could not be calculated if "A" doesn't appear in any of the vectors (that's the case with vector `7`).
- If names do not match, the calculation doesn't have any sense, that's why I throw an error (`stop`)

This is the function code:

```
calcDif = function(lst1, lst2){
  if (!identical(names(lst1), names(lst2))){
    stop("Names do not match!")
  }

  difs = list()
  for (i in names(lst1)){
    idx1 = min(which(lst1[[i]] == "A"))
    idx2 = min(which(lst2[[i]] == "A"))
    difs[[i]] = idx1 - idx2
  }
  return(difs)
}
```

If I run it with your data, I get:

```
calcDif(lst1, lst2)
$`4`
[1] 1

$`7`
[1] NaN

Warning messages:
1: In min(which(lst1[[i]] == "A")) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(which(lst2[[i]] == "A")) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

If I attempt to run it with lists of unmatching names, then:

```
calcDif(list(x = 1:2), lst2)
Error in calcDif(list(x = 1:2), lst2) : Names do not match!
```

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate your help, I'll try to work with this.

Comment: @pkha glad it helped. If it solves your problem, please consider clicking the check mark below the voting buttons to indicate that it is, indeed, a solution